# Percentage Formula Field based on Picklist values

Tags: formula-field

I have a picklist called state and each state has its own percentage rate. I created a percentage formula field where if the user select the State X, this percentage field should display the rate for that state. I wrote the following formula:

```
IF(ISPICKVAL(Estado__c , "São Paulo"), "4",
IF(ISPICKVAL(Estado__c , "Rio de Janeiro"),"4",
IF(ISPICKVAL(Estado__c , "Minas Gerais"), "4",
IF(ISPICKVAL(Estado__c , "Goiás"), "0", "Others"))))
```

Error: Formula result is data type (Text), incompatible with expected data type (Percent).

What's wrong? Can you help me with the eight formula for it?

Comment: First thing to try is to drop the quotes around the numbers i.e. use `4` instead of `"4"` etc and change `"Others"` to `0`. Using [CASE](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_a_h.htm&language=en_US#CASE) would be a bit clearer too.

Comment: Hi Keith! Thanks for your answer. I changed the "4" to 0.04 and "others" to 0.00 , and the formula worked. So, the formula is, just a small sample:
IF(ISPICKVAL(Estado__c , "São Paulo"), 0.04, 
IF(ISPICKVAL(Estado__c , "Rio de Janeiro"), 0.04, 
IF(ISPICKVAL(Estado__c , "Minas Gerais"), 0.04, 
IF(ISPICKVAL(Estado__c , "Rio Grande do Sul"), 0.03, 
IF(ISPICKVAL(Estado__c , "Amazonas"), 0.03, 
IF(ISPICKVAL(Estado__c , "Goiás"), 0.00, 0.00))))))))))))))))))))))))))

Comment: Good. Still think you should be using CASE though!

Comment: Case instaed of spickval?

Comment: Yeah - see techbusinessman's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something similar to:

```
Case(TEXT(Estado__c),
  "São Paulo", 4,
  "Rio de Janeiro", 4,
  "Minas Gerais, 4
  "Goiás", 0,
  0
)
```

In my opinion this becomes more readable than multiple IF statements. You can then imbed this into the current formula you are using.

Here is the link to documentation on the case field: [Salesforce Help: Formula - Case](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_a_h.htm&language=en_US#CASE)